# Decreasing the storage size of a production AWS RDS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an MySQL RDS instance that I use in a production environment (multi AZ). This instance is defined as "Provisioned IOPS" with 1,000GB of storage and 6,000 provisioned IOPS.
I would like to decrease both the storage and the amount of provisioned IOPS I'm paying for, as I no longer need them. I'm facing the following issues:

1. AWS does not allow decreasing the storage size of an RDS instance
2. Any change to the storage engine (storage size and/or type) takes forever on a DB that big (in the past I measured around 24-36 hours)

I already tried the following solutions:

1. Dump the current DB, create a new (smaller) instance and load the dumped data into it. This is bad because the dump/load process takes a very long time for such a big DB and I cannot allow this to happen on a production database.
2. Create a read replica to the main db, change its storage type and promote it to be the master. This fails because I can't even decrease the size of the replica.

Is there any other way of making this happen? I really want to avoid paying for an under-utilized DB instance.

Comment: I would suggest trying to make smaller instance with bigger IOPS for import and then decreasing IOPS. Not sure if it would work, thats why it's only a comment.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation recently, and this is how I solved it using [AWS DMS](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/):

1. Set the [necessary parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html#CHAP_Source.MySQL.AmazonManaged) for the RDS instance's parameter group
2. Dump the schema of the DB: `mysqldump -h <original-db-host> -u <db-user> -p --no-data --all-databases --set-gtid-purged=OFF > schema.sql`. This *only* includes the schema and no data, so this operation is relatively quick and reliable.
3. Dump the users and permissions: `mysqlpump -h <original-db-host> -u <db-user> -p --set-gtid-purged=OFF --exclude-databases=% --users >> schema.sql`
4. Remove the statements related to the following users from `schema.sql`:

   - `mysql.session`
   - `mysql.sys`
   - `rdsadmin`
   - the master user set when [creating the RDS instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html)
     These are created and managed by RDS/MySQL automatically, so creating/modifying them would fail
5. [Create a new DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateDBInstance.html), with the same settings as the original one, except for the reduced storage size.
6. Create the schema in the new DB instance: `mysql -h <new-db-host> -u <db-user> -p < schema.sql`
7. [Create a source DMS endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.Creating.html) for your original DB.
8. [Create a target DMS endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.Creating.html) for your new DB. [Make sure to set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.MySQL.html) `initstmt=SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` as "Extra connection attributes".
9. [Create a DMS replication instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_ReplicationInstance.html).
10. [Create a DMS task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.Creating.html) using the previously created DMS resources in step 7, 8 and 9. The simplest is if you select "Full load, ongoing replication" as a type, so the task will perform a full load, then also sync any subsequent changes. As for the mapping rules, `mysql`, `sys`,
    and `performance_schema` should be excluded because syncing these would fail. I also recommend enabling CloudWatch logs for debugging.
11. Wait until the full load is completed, then verify that ongoing changes are synced by the DMS task.
12. Switch the services that use the original DB to the new one.
13. Wait until no new updates are done on the original DB. This can be verified by looking at the "Last updated" column in the table statistics for the DMS task.
14. When you're confident that nothing is using the original DB anymore, stop it.
15. Clean up the AWS resources after a safety interval (e.g. a couple of days): old RDS instance, DMS task, DMS endpoints, DMS replication instance.

Note that this process is not easy, quite risky and time-consuming (may take multiple days) so I only recommend you do it if reducing the size results in a considerable cost saving.